# Understanding %DiskTime in Perfmon

Tags: performance, windows, hard-drive, perfmon

I have a server that's been jumping around `100-700` %DiskTime for the past few days.

I understand this indicates an I/O bottleneck -- but what do I do from here? What do I need to check or change in regards to the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use process explorer (procexp) to track down the hog.  You'll need to add additional columns in the view pane specifically for disk reads and disk writes.  Once you have the culprit you can go from there (engage the vendor or developer).

You'll likely want to see what that process is doing and you can use process monitor (procmon) to do that.  When you launch procmon, you'll likely want to filter out everything but the process you're investigating.

Those two tools come with their own help documentation (and it's pretty good).  To deep dive even further, I'd recommend the windows internals books from Mark Russinovich.

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

[Sysinternals Process Utilities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533)

[Windows Internals Books](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx)